# RabbitMQ 3.11.x : Enable Feature Flags using advanced.config or Enviroment Variable on Existing Node of RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, erlang-otp

OS : Windows 10
RabbitMQ version used : 3.8.8, 3.9.13, 3.11.x

1. Installed the RabbitMQ 3.8.8 and upgraded to RabbitMQ 3.9.13.
2. Now need to upgrade RabbitMQ 3.9.13 to 3.11.x. I have referred https://www.rabbitmq.com/feature-flags.html.
3. Before upgrade we need to enable the respective feature flags. I have enabled the feature flags using rabbitmqctl enable_feature_flag  and this is working successfully.
4. Tried to enable feature flags on the same/existing node using below ways and failed.
   a.advanced.config (config parameter)
   b.Environment variable

Request you to provide the solution to proceed on this using the advanced.config or Environment variable to upgrade RabbitMQ version 3.8.8 -> 3.9.13 to 3.11.0 on the existing node.